# Executar evento em botão tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estou com dificuldade em fazer com que o o botão execute uma def e faça uma criptografia simples e, em seguida, exiba na tela.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Application(): 
    def __init__(self, toplevel): 
        toplevel.title('teste')
        self.fr1 = Frame(toplevel) 
        self.fr1.pack() 
        self.fr2 = Frame(toplevel) 
        self.fr2.pack() 
        self.fr3 = Frame(toplevel) 
        self.fr3.pack() 
        self.fr4 = Frame(toplevel,pady=10) 
        self.fr4.pack() 
        self.fr5 = Frame(toplevel,pady=10) 
        self.fr5.pack()

        Label(self.fr1,
        text='Msg corpo ', 
        fg='darkblue',font=('Verdana','12','bold'), heigh=5).pack()
        Label(self.fr1,
        text='msg instrução', 
        fg='darkblue',font=('Verdana','8','bold'), heigh=5).pack()

        fonte1=('Verdana','10','bold')
        Label(self.fr2,text='Digite a mensagem: ',font=fonte1,width=20).pack(side=LEFT)  
        self.nome=Entry(self.fr2,width=50,font=fonte1)
        self.nome.focus_force()
        self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)

        Label(self.fr3,text='Chave: ', font=fonte1, width=20).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.cifra=Entry(self.fr3, width=15, font=fonte1)
        self.cifra.pack()

        self.travar=Button(self.fr4, text='Cripitografar', fg='black', )
        self.destravar=Button(self.fr4, text='Descriptografar', fg='black', )
        self.travar.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.destravar.pack(side=RIGHT)

        Label(self.fr5,text=' = ', font=fonte1, width=20).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.msg=Label(self.fr5, width=50, font=fonte1)
        self.msg.pack()

        def travar():
                nomes = self.nome.get()  
                cifras = self.cifra.get()
                for i in range(len(nome)):
                    print(chr(ord(nome[i]) + cifra), end='')
                print('')
      
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
#raiz=Tk() 
##Janela(raiz) 
#raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo segue abaixo um pequeno exemplo:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def muda_title(nome=""):
    root.title(f'Hello {nome}')

muda_title("Tkinter")
button = Button(master=root, text='Muda o titulo', command=lambda: muda_title("Rodrigo"))
button.pack()
```

Alterei um pouco o código que vc fez, mas ainda precisa ser melhorado.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Application():
    def __init__(self, toplevel):
        toplevel.title('teste')
        self.fr1 = Frame(toplevel)
        self.fr1.pack()
        self.fr2 = Frame(toplevel)
        self.fr2.pack()
        self.fr3 = Frame(toplevel)
        self.fr3.pack()
        self.fr4 = Frame(toplevel,pady=10)
        self.fr4.pack()
        self.fr5 = Frame(toplevel,pady=10)
        self.fr5.pack()

        Label(self.fr1,
        text='Msg corpo ',
        fg='darkblue',font=('Verdana','12','bold'), heigh=5).pack()
        Label(self.fr1,
        text='msg instrução',
        fg='darkblue',font=('Verdana','8','bold'), heigh=5).pack()

        self.fonte1=('Verdana','10','bold')
        Label(self.fr2,text='Digite a mensagem: ',font=self.fonte1,width=20).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.nome=Entry(self.fr2,width=50,font=self.fonte1)
        self.nome.focus_force()
        self.nome.pack(side=LEFT)

        Label(self.fr3,text='Chave: ', font=self.fonte1, width=20).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.cifra=Entry(self.fr3, width=15, font=self.fonte1)
        self.cifra.pack()

        self.trv = Button(self.fr4, text='Cripitografar', fg='black', command=lambda: self.travar())
        self.des = Button(self.fr4, text='Descriptografar', fg='black', command=lambda: self.travar())
        self.trv.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.des.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.msg = Label(self.fr5,text=f' = ', font=self.fonte1, width=20)
        self.msg.pack(side=LEFT)

    def travar(self):
        self.msg.destroy()
        nomes = self.nome.get()
        cifras = self.cifra.get()
        mensagem = "".join([chr(ord(caracter) + ord(cifras)) for caracter in nomes])
        self.msg = Label(self.fr5,text=f' = {mensagem}', font=self.fonte1, width=20)
        self.msg.pack(side=LEFT)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**O que deve ser melhorado**

1. `self.trv` e `self.des` estão chamando a mesma função. Porém a segunda deveria ser uma para descriptografar, ou destravar
2. A função travar espera que `chave` seja apenas um caracter, se colocar mais que um em `chave` irá gerar uma exceção que deve ser tratada.

**Todavia**

O código responde à pergunta de *executar uma função a partir de um botão*

Espero que ajude.